# Permanent redirect issue accessing a private bucket on S3 using ECL

Tags: web8, ecl, s3

Looking for anyone who has successfully connected to a private S3 bucket from Web 8 using the external content library connection.

I am able to connect to a public bucket successfully. However, when I try to connect to a *private* bucket, I receive the following response from the endpoint in aws when I paste the `<FullBucketUrl>` from the `ecl.xml` config in my browser.

```
<Error>
  <Code>PermanentRedirect</Code>
  <Message>
    The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.
  </Message>
  <Bucket>Private-Bucket</Bucket>
  <Endpoint>s3.amazonaws.com</Endpoint>
  <RequestId>68D6A3E11776FCC1</RequestId>
  <HostId>b24iR0OcgTWX7+JaLVhZfz22KI8QK5Gh4qWXAgf7GmFyDG64TwPY5ELSgMcrwnefeLfSBJCmrgQ=</HostId>
</Error>
```

This is from my public bucket config that is working correctly.

```
<FullBucketUrl xmlns="http://www.sdltridion.com/S3EclProvider/Configuration">https://ecl-s3-test.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/</FullBucketUrl>
```

Yes, I am using correct `S3AccessId`, `S3SecretKey`, `S3BucketName`, from AWS.

So I guess my question is, what is the `<FullBucketUrl>` I should be using to connect to private S3 bucket from `ecl.xml` and/or "other" credentials I need to pass to access a list of items inside the bucket, considering I am getting the `PermanentRedirect` on all `<FullBucketUrl>` below

I have tried these so far, with no luck.

```
<FullBucketUrl xmlns="http://www.sdltridion.com/S3EclProvider/Configuration">https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/name-of-bucket/</FullBucketUrl>
<FullBucketUrl xmlns="http://www.sdltridion.com/S3EclProvider/Configuration">https://name-of-bucket.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/</FullBucketUrl>
<FullBucketUrl xmlns="http://www.sdltridion.com/S3EclProvider/Configuration">http://name-of-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/</FullBucketUrl>
<FullBucketUrl xmlns="http://www.sdltridion.com/S3EclProvider/Configuration">https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/</FullBucketUrl>
<FullBucketUrl xmlns="http://www.sdltridion.com/S3EclProvider/Configuration">https://aws.amazon.com/s3/</FullBucketUrl>
<FullBucketUrl xmlns="http://www.sdltridion.com/S3EclProvider/Configuration">https://autoscaling.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/</FullBucketUrl>
```

---

Stacktrace (which is what I would expect considering the above S3 error).

```
2017-07-24 12:46:26,813 [4] ERROR UI.Model - 
System.Exception: Unable to get the list of items ---> System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Server stack trace: 
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.Service.Client.ISessionAwareEclService.GetList(String parentItemUri, Int32 pageIndex, EclItemTypes itemTypes, IEnumerable`1 basedOnSchema)
at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.UI.Model.Services.GeneralImpl.GetList(String id, Int32 pageIndex, Filter filter, Int32 columns)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.UI.Model.Services.GeneralImpl.GetList(String id, Int32 pageIndex, Filter filter, Int32 columns)
at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.UI.Model.Services.General.GetList(String id, Int32 pageIndex, Filter filter, Int32 columns)
at SyncInvokeGetList(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
at Tridion.Web.UI.Core.Extensibility.DataExtenderOperationInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
2017-07-24 12:46:29,767 [4] DEBUG UI.DataExtenders - Process response for command 'GetListActivityInstances' id=''
2017-07-24 12:46:29,767 [4] DEBUG UI.DataExtenders - Updating element 'tcm:ListActivityInstances'
2017-07-24 12:46:30,767 [4] DEBUG UI.DataExtenders - Process response for command 'GetListActivityInstances' id=''
2017-07-24 12:46:30,767 [4] DEBUG UI.DataExtenders - Updating element 'tcm:ListActivityInstances'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So looks like you need to specify the `<S3RegionEndpoint>` and the `<FullBucketUrl>` within the `ExternalContentLibrary.xml` S3 configuration I got from [here](https://vikaskumarblogs.wordpress.com/2017/04/06/creating-sdl-tridionweb-ecl-provider-for-aws-s3-bucket/comment-page-1/).

```xml
<S3RegionEndpoint xmlns="http://www.sdltridion.com/S3EclProvider/Configuration">us-east-2</S3RegionEndpoint>
```

```xml
<FullBucketUrl xmlns="http://www.sdltridion.com/S3EclProvider/Configuration">https://name-of-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/</FullBucketUrl>
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, please mark it as answer, if you have found a resolution already